# What does coinfinite mean?

Tags: set-theory, infinity-categories

I'm reading up on [maximal sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_set) and the word "coinfinite" pops up in the first sentence. I tried searching on Wolfram Mathworld as well as Google, but nothing concrete has come up. What does it mean and in what context can it be used?

Comment: Limited amount of money? ... Less frivolously, I think the suggestion of Gerald Edgar sounds very plausible

Comment: Coinfinito would mean completely broke.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps it means the complement is infinite.
Certainly "cofinite" and "cocountable" are used this way.

Comment: Yes, this is the standard usage.

Comment: Comathematician is a machine for turning cotheorems into fee.

Comment: On the other hand, 'cofinite volume' usually refers to a quotient space having finite volume.

Answer (score 1):

See Wikipedia article "[Cofiniteness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinite)".

Comment: That article has no mention of "coinfinite" however.


Comment: @Gerald Edgar: That's right, sorry, I seem to have misread the original question.